# WP7 BitmapImage Memory Leak when CreateOptions is NOT DelayCreation

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

BitmapImage leaks memory when CreateOptions is anything BUT DelayCreation AND is put in the visual tree (either in an Image or ImageBrush)

I am seeing this on the Emulator with SDK 7.1 AND on the Phone (HTC Titan)
Steps :

1. Open new WP Project
2. Start a new dispatchertimer in App.xaml.cs that prints Memory Usage (DeviceStatus) every second and does GC.Collect(). (consider newing up a byte array with a size calculated to be a little less than (MemoryUsageLimit - CurrentMemoryUsage))
3. Add a StackPanel named ImagePanel inside ContentPanel
4. Add 2 Buttons in ContentPanel (1 for creating and adding 10 images
   to ImagePanel with code and one to Clear the children of ImagePanel)
5. Find a high resolution image (just so memory usage is easily
   visible) and host it on your local IIS
6. When button 1 is clicked write :

   ```
   Random rand = new Random();
   for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
   {
      //use 192.168.55.100 instead of localhost when running on the phone
      //to be able to see traffic in fiddler.Change localhost to machinename for the emulator
      var uri = "http://localhost/images/bigimage.jpg?tc=" + rand.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
      var bitmap = new BitmapImage 
                       {
                         UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                         CreateOptions = BackgroundCreation //or None or DelayCreation
                       };
     ImagePanel.Children.Add(new Image { Source = bitmap });
   }
   ```
7. When button 2 is clicked write :

   ```
   ImagePanel.Children.Clear();
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();
   ```

Try with all the variations of CreateOptions and watch the difference in memory.
Keep adding and removing elements and see with which CreateOption you are going to get an OutOfMemoryException.

Can someone verify this?

Comment: @atomaras - Just because you demand that it goes away doesn't mean that the GC will actually do it. There's no leak here.

Comment: Isnt getting an OutOfMemoryException a good indicator that its NOT collectable?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you call `ImagePanel.Children.Clear` via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`? `BackgroundCreation` creates new threads in the background, so does clearing it on the UI thread help? (I haven't test the code, so I'm assuming a memory leak exists).

Comment: I encountered a similar behavior in one of my apps. I had to manually set the source of all image controls to null to avoid leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this expected behavior beceause the BitmapImage relies on GDI+? (and thus is essentially unmanaged code?) IIRC It's not the ImagePanel leaking but the BitmapImage that is being created over and over again.

If you assign the value to the same BitmapImage object the problem shouldn't occur. You do need to do this on the drawing thread though otherwise GDI will have a fit)
Personally whenever I work with images in WP7 I use [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/releases/view/53740) instead of the native classes. The output can be directly assigned to an image control but it can be loaded asynchronously, uses less memory and manipulation is much much faster